# Evaluating a 2D function from a list and add the result to the list

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have a list like this

```
data = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}
```

and a function

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2;
```

I would like to evaluate this function taking `x` and `y` from `data`. I can do this if the `f`  only has one variable, just using `f /@ data[[All, {}]]` for instance. Additionally, I would like add the result to the list like this

```
Newdata = {{1, 2, 3, f[2, 3]}, {4, 5, 6, f[5, 6]}}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Are you saying you want to call `f` on the previous two entries, and that you may repeat this operation more than once?

Comment: Remember you can do f@@{x,y} to get f[x,y] - and f@@@{{x,y},{x,y},{x,y}} to get {f[x, y], f[x, y], f[x, y]}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
MapThread[Append, {data, f @@@ data[[All, -2 ;;]]}]

(* {{1, 2, 3, f[2, 3]}, {4, 5, 6, f[5, 6]}} *)
```

Or alternatively,

```
Append[#, f @@ #[[-2 ;;]]] & /@ data

(* {{1, 2, 3, f[2, 3]}, {4, 5, 6, f[5, 6]}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

just write another function

```
g[{x_, y_, z_}] :=
    {x, y, z, f[y, z]};

{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}} //
Map[g]
```

Answer (score 2):

With `ReplaceAll`:

```
data = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};

f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2

data /. {a_, b_, c_} :> {a, b, c, f[b, c]}
```

{{1, 2, 3, 13}, {4, 5, 6, 61}}